# Centering only the top index menu items in CSS horizontal drop-down menu

Tags: html, css

How do I modify the css such that only the top items (index items) are centerered, the sub items are fine (as they are already positioned to the left)?

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">File</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Edit</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#nogo">View</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 3-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

/*HORIZONTAL DROP-DOWN MENU */
#menu{
padding:0;
margin:0;
position: fixed;
top: 33px;
left: 0px;
font-size: 8pt;
}
#menu ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
#menu li{
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
} 

#menu li a{
width:120px;
height: 20px;
display: block;
text-decoration:none;
line-height: 20px;
background-color: #A9BBD3;
color: #FFF;
} 

#menu li a:hover{
background-color: #446087;
} 

#menu ul ul{
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
visibility:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way it to target the top level specifically using the `>` [CSS child combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ywWg5/)**

```
#menu > ul > li > a{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Adding this rule will center the top level text while leaving the sub-menu text left justified.

Comment: This won't work as intended since the sub menus are also in `ul` tags. It will center the top level text AS WELL AS the first sub-menu text.

Comment: hmm I guess it does... I thought it would have also centered `Link 1-2` etc.. sorry

Comment: This works great! Is it possible to add some padding-left: 5px to the sub menu items?

Comment: @JasonKelly - Sure, the easiest way would simply to give your submenu list items a class and then target that class via CSS, or you could use two separate rules to set the padding. One rule for the top level and another for the sub-level items. I'd recommend the first method and give them a class if possible.

Answer (score 1):

example http://jsfiddle.net/zhprP/
add a class to the top element and other class to subitems like

```
<li class='top'>File</li>
    <li class='sub'>...</li>
```

and in css apply:

```
.top{
     text-align:center;
  }
 .sub{text-align:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new class and then add that class to your top items.. for example

```
#menu li.top_item{
    text-align: center;
}
```

and then for the html:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li class="top_item"><a href="#nogo">File</a>
<ul>
<li class="top_item"><a href="#nogo">Save</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 1-3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="top_item"><a href="#nogo">Edit</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-1</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-2</a></li>
<li><a href="#nogo">Link 2-3</a></li>
...
```